# Cron every minute to trigger url via CURL

Tags: linux, curl, cron

I want to set a CRON task to trigger an URL every minutes (via CURL).
That seems pretty simple, I searched and wrote this :

```
* * * * * curl -—silent "https://urltotrigger.com/page.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I added that to the crontab -e and saved. But it seems that the url is not triggered.

Don't understand why, everything seems correct? Can you help me please? Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cron entry is wrong. If you need it to be run every 1 minute, it should be like this:

```
*/1 * * * * curl -—silent "https://urltotrigger.com/page.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```